# Degeneracy, spherical harmonics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator, spherical-harmonics

In a 3D oscillator, the energy levels are known to be $(n_x + n_y + n_z + \frac{3}{2})\hbar \omega = (n + \frac{3}{2})\hbar \omega$.

Say for $n = 1$, any of the $n$'s can be $1$ and the rest are $0$. For $n = 2$ and $3$, same concept applies.

How do I use this information about degeneracy to suggest values of $\ell$ in spherical harmonics $Y_\ell^m$?

Comment: Possibly useful: http://quantummechanics.ucsd.edu/ph130a/130_notes/node244.html